# When does Microsoft Office 2010 Beta expire?

Tags: license, office-2010-beta

I lost my key and my product expired without activating.  What is strange is that besides a popup on startup, it appears to let you use the app.  Is this only for a short amount of time?

Comment: From what I have read on MS site, you will not have access to any further updates, or downloading add-ins etc.

Comment: So it will keep on working? That would be nice (as long as I don't encouter bugs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [beta expires](http://www.pcworld.com/article/182812-2/faq_microsoft_office_2010_beta.html) on [October 2010.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/office2010volact/thread/99e093a5-f53b-4ce1-bc23-4d76e972c13e) You can keep previewing till then then, after that you may opt to purchase it or try the trial.

> In the end-user licensing agreement
>   (EULA) that accompanies the beta, the
>   company starkly says: "The software
>   will stop running on 31/10/2010. You
>   will not receive any other notice. You
>   may not be able to access data used
>   with the software when it stops
>   running."